# Notation question regarding open sets/differential equations

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In the following context what do  $\ J(x_0), \alpha(x_0) $ & $\ \beta(x_0) $ stand for. I.e is $\alpha(x_0) $ a real number near $\ x_0 $.

Consider a differential equation $\ x_0 = f(x) $ where $\ f : W \mapsto \Bbb R  $ (and where $W$ is an
open subset of $\Bbb R $). Assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable.

**Claim:** For each $\ x_0 \in W $ there exist real number $\ \alpha(x_0) < 0 < \beta(x_0) $ so that

(a) whenever $\ 0 \in J \subset R $ and $\ x: J \mapsto W $ is a solution of $\ x_0 = f(x); x(0) = x_0 $ then $\ J \subset J(x_0) $.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to say for sure without knowing the source of this claim.  You should provide it.  It's also not clear to me how $x_0 = f(x)$ defines a differential equation.

That said, I suspect you could rewrite the claim as follows:  for each $x_0 \in W$ there exists an interval $J(x_0) = (\alpha(x_0), \beta(x_0)$ so that

- $0 \in J(x_0)$
- Any other interval which contains $0$ and which admits a solution to this differential equation (with initial condition $x(0) = x_0$) is contained in $J$.

As a slogan, "for any $x_0 \in W$ there is a maximal interval about the origin on which $f(x) = x_0$ has a solution with $x(0) = x_0$."